# BitTorrent Protocol Seeding

Tags: bittorrent, p2p

Let's say there's a seeder that does not have UPnP enabled nor does he have port forwarding set up. Does the seeder initiate connections with other nodes that do have port forwarding enabled to seed to them ? If so how does that happen ?

Comment: UPnP is just a form of port forwarding, if a client does not have port forwarding, then their client will be limited in which clients can connect to it